# What is the meaning of cmake command lines

Tags: unix, directory, cmake, makefile

I am trying to build a software following some instructions on line.

```
cd app
mkdir -p build/Release
cd build/Release
cmake ../..
make installpyplusplus && cmake .
make .
```

My questions:

1. What does "../.." after `cmake` do or mean?
2. What is the significance of the dot after `make`?
3. what will 'make installpyplusplus && cmake .' ?

Comment: Please read [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/dot-and-dot-dot-105312/). To which I add that `../..` is the parent directory of the parent directory (in a Unix system, in Windows it would be `..\..`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `cmake` application looks for one file in special, called `CMakeLists.txt`.
So by running:

```
cmake ../..
```

It's like saying to `cmake` that the `CMakeLists.txt` is two directories below, like described by MERose.

The `cmake` command creates many files at your current working directory (CWD, the directory you ran the command from), and among them is a file called `Makefile`, which has rules about which files to compile/build/copy/write/whatever and how to do it.

So when you run:

```
make .
```

You are telling the `make` application that the `Makefile` file is at your CWD. It's the same as running:

```
make
```

That looks for the `Makefile` file at your CWD.

Concluding, `.` is the CWD, and `..` is one level below.

EX: If your CWD is `/Users/yourname/`

- `.` represents `/Users/yourname/`
- `..` represents `/Users/`
- `../.` represents `/Users/`
- `../..` represents `/`

And so on...

> what will 'make installpyplusplus && cmake .' ?

When you use `&&` the commands will be executed sequentially if the first command returns true (exit status zero). So, in the case you said, `make installpyplusplus` will be run, and after it's done (it can create a `CMakeLists.txt`, I don't know what you are running), if it returns true, the command `cmake .` will be run, and if the `CMakeLists.txt` is there, it will run properly.

**BONUS:**

If you run:

```
make -j4
```

You will separate the build process in 4 instances (you can change 4 by anything you want)! Multi-threading magic will make it build faster if you have more than one processor core available :)

Comment: `make .` does not point make at the current directory; it rather asks the make system to create the current directory. In most cases this is nonsense, but for CMake generated files it triggers a rebuild.